# Creating an object with the value of a private method

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have this code:

```
public Foo {
    public enum Bar {FooBar, BarFoo, FooFoo, BarBar}
    public Foo (Bar bar) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Now, when creating an object, I have several different cases for what migth be created: `FooBar, BarFoo, FooFoo, BarBar`. Depending on what these cases are, how might I execute a different method for each?
I suppose I am looking to do something a bit like this:

```
public Foo {
    public enum Bar {FooBar, BarFoo, FooFoo, BarBar}
    public Foo (Bar bar) {
        switch (bar) {
            case FooBar: fooBar(bar); break;
            case BarFoo: barFoo(bar); break;
            case FooFoo: fooFoo(bar); break;
            case BarBar: barBar(bar); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    void fooBar (Bar bar) {
        //Treat this as the constructor class for case FooBar
    }
    void barFoo (Bar bar) {
        //Treat this as the constructor class for case barFoo
    }
    void fooFoo (Bar bar) {
        //Treat this as the constructor class for case fooFoo
    }
    void barBar (Bar bar) {
        //Treat this as the constructor class for case barBar
    }
}
```

In addition, is this a bad practice? Would it be better to create a separate class for each case and drop the enum?

Comment: I think you can use factory method pattern for this case. http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html

Comment: Ist there a reason to use an enum? The solutions below use polymorphic methods on an enum, but your example does not show why you need an enum at all. In this case you should follow your intuition and create a separate class for each case. Another hint could be the [visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

Move case-specific code into `enum Bar`, and use the override in the constructor:

```
public Foo {
    public enum Bar {
        FooBar {
            @Override
            public void configure(Foo obj) {
                ... // Code specific to this enum case
            }
        }
    ,   BarFoo {
            @Override
            public void configure(Foo obj) {
                ... // Code specific to this enum case
            }
        }
    ,   FooFoo {
            @Override
            public void configure(Foo obj) {
                ... // Code specific to this enum case
            }
        }
    ,   BarBar {
            @Override
            public void configure(Foo obj) {
                ... // Code specific to this enum case
            }
        }
    ;
    public abstract void configure(Foo obj);
    }
    public Foo (Bar bar) {
        bar.configure(this);
    }
}
```

The code inside each override of `configure(Foo)` gets access to the instance of `Bar` being configured by the constructor, letting you replace `switch` with a virtual dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement a method inside the enum to execute it directly. It removes the unnecessary `switch` statement and methods.

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo (Bar bar) {
        bar.execute();
    }

    public enum Bar {
        FooBar, BarFoo, FooFoo, BarBar;
        public void execute() {
            // TODO
            // System.out.println(this.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need an unique method for each of the enum instance, make the `execute` method abstract and `@Override` it for each one.

```
public enum Bar {
    FooBar {
        @Override
        public void execute() { }
    }, BarFoo {
        @Override
        public void execute() { }
    }, FooFoo {
        @Override
        public void execute() { }
    }, BarBar {
        @Override
        public void execute() { }
    };

    public abstract void execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums can also have methods so you could add abstract method and override it for every case you need, something like this:

```
public enum Bar {
    FooBar {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            // your code for FooBar
        }
    },
    BarFoo {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            // your code for BarFoo
        }
    },
    FooFoo {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            // .....
        }
    }, 
    BarBar {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            // .....
        }
    };
    public abstract void  doSomething();
}
```